# Empty window space for Eclipse e4 RCP part extracted to fragment in separate plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have successfully built my first Eclipse 4 RCP application by extending the PartSashContainer of the demo content to also show a second Part.

Now I have tried to move the second part to a separate plugin package and import it as fragment. This works up to the point that the new application neither freezes nor throws any explicit exception. It also divides the space of the window into even parts and shows the main part. Unfortunately the part of the window which is supposed to show the content of the second part from the extracted fragment is completely empty.
Default constructors for both parts are called. "@PostConstruct public void createComposite(Composite parent)" to be found in both parts however is only called for the main part and not for the second.
I have set all parts to be visible and to be rendered without any difference.
Due to the lack of errors and otherwise strange behavior I'm quite convinced to have set all required IDs in both *.e4xmi files.

Any ideas where there might be the difference between the incorporated and the extracted approach?

I uploaded both projects as zip file to [link](http://www.xup.to/dl,20047267/MinimumWorkingExample.zip/)

Comment: Do you mean a fragment.e4xmi or one of the various other things called 'fragments' in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to a fragment with fragment.e4xmi. As far as I can tell it appears that I have set all Element IDs and Featurenames correctly - the application at least neither freezes nor shows any explicit exceptions.

Comment: This should work, I have plenty of fragments working like this. Is the part declared with 'Visible' set and 'To be Rendered' unset?

Comment: I have set the respective part to be neither "visible" nor "to be rendered" in fragment.e4xmi. However the associated handler is to call myPart.setVisible(true) and myPart.setToBeRendered(true). From my understanding this should be the same? I just tried it with both check boxes unset/set and mutually set but my buttons simply don't show in neither of the configurations.

Comment: Mine all have Visible set and To be Rendered unset. Looking at my code I am using `EPartService.showPart(id, PartState.ACTIVATE)`

Comment: I boiled it down to a minimum "working" example and changed the question text accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have run into this:

http://blog.vogella.com/2012/11/23/eclipse4-and-postconstruct-and-predestroy-not-called-javax-annotation/

To solve the issue, you need to add `javax.annotation` as a **package dependency** instead of plug-in dependency to the MANIFEST.MF of the plug-in containing the fragment.